# First div tag among the four div tags at different locations

Tags: html, css-selectors

I have four divs at different positions with same `class` and `id`. I want to get only the first `div` using `css` selector, can any one help

Comment: **id must be unique**. The sequence of *class* children has been build during building a html page. Provide your divs in their order in the html page and define which div are you need to get.

Comment: You can do it with css first-child selector. Follow this url for demo-
 https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add another class name to only the first divs

Ex:

```
<div class=“AllDivs FirstDiv”> div text </div>
```

And then in the css you can do

```
  .AllDivs.FirstDiv{
            Desired position
   }
```

On a further note... they shouldn’t all have the same id names. Id’s are supposed to be only for special occasions. So they should only represent one instance of something that needs styled